# Unable to insert current username into custom table through html form

Tags: php, html

I have a custom html form from which I am trying to insert records into a custom table .My problem is getting the current user name and inserting that value into the custom table. When the user clicks the Submit button the code below should fire. This is my php code:

```
<?php>
session_start;
require_once "wp-load.php";
require_once "dbconfig.php";
global $wpdb, $current_user;
$current_user=wp_get_current_user();
$table_name="persons";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
              'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
              'last_name'  => $_POST['last_name'],
               'email'     => $_POST['email'],
               'telephone' => $_POST['telephone'],
               'user_name' => [$current_user]
               )
          );
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Been working on this for hours now, unable to find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_current_user` returns a `WP_User` object.  You'll need to pull the name out of that in order to send it try `$current_user->display_name` in your insert statement.  On that note, you should absolutely not be inserting unsanitized user entered data into your database.  Please look into SQL injection and input sanitization.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will definitely take care of sql injection. Just to update, to get the user name the following is the code: $current_user=wp_get_current_user();
$current_username = $current_user->user_login;

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code to insert user name into a custom table:

```
$current_user=wp_get_current_user();
$current_username = $current_user->user_login;
```